# Fuse 6.1.0.redhat-379 : ResolutionException on creating child container with testFuse profile

Tags: fuse

Tried to Deploy profile "testFuse" into the child container and got this provision exception

Provision Exception:

```
    org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve dummy/0.0.0: missing requirement [dummy/0.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=testFuse; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.0.SNAPSHOT,1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]" [caused by: Unable to resolve testFuse/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [testFuse/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.activemq.camel.component)(version>=5.9.0)(!(version>=6.0.0)))"]

      at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populateResource(Candidates.java:285)

      at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populate(Candidates.java:153)

      at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:148)

      at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentBuilder.resolve(DeploymentBuilder.java:226)

      at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent.doUpdate(DeploymentAgent.java:521)

      at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent$2.run(DeploymentAgent.java:252)

      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)

      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)

      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```